# iOS - how to be notified when a thread (using GCD) ends it's job

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, nsthread, grand-central-dispatch

I'm start to use GCD, and I need to know when a certain thread has ended it's job.

My code:

```
dispatch_queue_t registerDeviceQueue = dispatch_queue_create("RegisterDevice", NULL);
dispatch_async(registerDeviceQueue, ^{
    [self registerDevice];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [aiRegisterDevice stopAnimating];
    });
});
dispatch_release(registerDeviceQueue);
```

I need to know when this tread has ended, so that the UIActivityView can stop.
The way it is now, it's stops before the thread ends.

Thanks,

RL

Comment: Are you calling `[aiRegisterDevice startAnimating]` **before** the first `dispatch_async()`? Where is that happening?

Comment: Hi, yes. I'm calling in viewWillAppear.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling in -viewWillAppear.
The question is that inside [self registerDevice], i call a web service, and receive data from it. And I see that the ActivityIndicator of the status bar works after my AI stops... That means that i still receive data...

Comment: And that would mean that `registerDevice` performs an asynchronous request, since `stopAnimating` won't be called until the method ends. You should call `stopAnimating` in your success/error download callback. It's difficult to really answer your question since `[self registerDevice]` could be doing anything really...

Comment: So, it would be best that the class called has a delegate method, set this class as delegate, and then call the delegate to stop animating. Correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd set up a group and use `dispatch_group_wait` to continue only when the computation has finished. To take your example:

```
dispatch_queue_t registerDeviceQueue = dispatch_queue_create("RegisterDevice", NULL);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_async(group, registerDeviceQueue, ^{
    [self registerDevice];
});

dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); // Block until we're ready
// Now we're good to call it:
[aiRegisterDevice stopAnimating];

dispatch_release(registerDeviceQueue);
dispatch_release(group);
```

Or, if you want to prevent the callback blocking use `dispatch_group_notify`:

```
dispatch_queue_t registerDeviceQueue = dispatch_queue_create("RegisterDevice", NULL);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_async(group, registerDeviceQueue, ^{
    [self registerDevice];
}); // In this version, the group won't block


// This block gets called asynchronously when the above code is done:
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [aiRegisterDevice stopAnimating];
});

dispatch_release(registerDeviceQueue);
dispatch_release(group);
```

Comment: Should we call `dispatch_release` inside `dispatch_group_notify ` block?